# Wave shaped responsive header with CSS

Tags: html, css, header, rounding

I'm trying to realize a wave-shaped header for a website...
It should look like that (no comment on the gradient, not my choice lol)

[image: Waved shape with CSS... how?!]

I tested some part of codes I found online to make this effect with CSS but when I try to edit something to make the wave adaptive to different kind of devices, everything goes down... With percentage it's quite difficult to me to find the exact point where the first curved shaped has to end and the next has to begin, I am left with some no needed straight line...

I even tried to use a SVG file to solve the issue but... you can imagine...

Anyone can help me to realize this? Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```css
#wave {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background: purple;


}
  #wave:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 40%;
    width: 65%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    right: -50px;
    top: 85px;
  }
  #wave:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 40%;
    width: 65%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: purple;
    left: -10%;
    top: 57px;
  }
```

```html
    <header id="wave">
      ...    
    </header>
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: Use SVG to achieve this result.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 edited and posted!

Comment: @cloned it would be nice to know more about your advice, thanks!

Comment: @Simone I can recommend something that's not done purely by CSS but with Adobe xd or Figma using the 'pen' tool, it's a hundred times easier and you can export it into an SVG and attach it into your page